# Eclipse file list in alphabetic order, independent from folder structure

Tags: eclipse, file, search, navigator

I'm looking a way to quickly find a file in the eclipse Project Explorer/Navigator without knowing in which sub folder I need to look for it.

The best way would be to have Project Explorer which just shows all source code files in the active project in alpabetic order.

Alternative a "filter text" box at the top of the Project Explorer/Navigator would also work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+R</kbd> (lookup resource). With Eclipse 3.7, you can even include parts of the path if you prepend the pattern with `*` (i.e. `*/test/logback.xml` won't find `project/src/logback.xml`).

For types, use <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+T</kbd>